# Load balancing with HAProxy for chat app by chat room

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, haproxy

I'm making a chat app in Rails and using Node.js. I want to load balance with HAProxy, but it's important that all users in a specific chat room are on the same server. How can I achieve this? I've been searching Google, assuming the intel would be out there because this must be a common issue, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use session cookies, it's well described in this documentation : http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: Thanks! I realized I was asking the wrong question. We're going with Redis and the last diagram in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/06/15/learning-redis-part-6-redis-publish-subscribe.aspx